# Python reading file not working through tkinter file chooser

Tags: python, file, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

filedir = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(filedir)

items = open(filedir, 'a+')

text = items.read()
print(text)
```

When I run the code and select a file, it doesn't output anything. Putting the file location manually in the code still outputs nothing, and the .txt file definitely has content.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you save the contents in the txt file?

Comment: Open file using mode 'a+' will put the file pointer at the end of the file.  So subsequent `read()` will return nothing.  If you just want to read the file content, open it using mode 'r' instead.

Answer (score 0):

The mode in which you are trying to open the file is not valid that's why U are unable to read the file. Try using `r+` mode to open, read and write (if already exists) the file.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

filedir = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(filedir)

items = open(filedir, 'r+')

text = items.read()
print(text)
```